# SAM3x8e can't program over serial

Tags: programming, crystal, atmel, clock-speed, serial-bus

**UPDATE: Jan 2022.** I put together a new pcb. This one has the JTAG header and I have an ATMEL-ICE. Otherwise the processor and support layout is mostly the same. I stripped the program down to simply turning on and off LEDs and sending a text out the serial ports every 1/2 second. I even went back to the Arduino IDE to make it the simplest possible code.

1. If I use RESET and ERASE buttons, The Arduino IDE can flash over the serial port. This is through a USB to RS232 adapter and on the pcb a MAX232 with a level shift for 3.3v. This loads without issue but does not run upon reset.
2. I can flash the same binary to the flash with the TOOLS menu on ATMEL STUDIO and the ATMEL ICE. I can change the bits to switch to boot from flash 0 as well. (The Arduino IDE also does this after it flashes the file over). I can verify I am flashing to section 0 and set to boot from section 0.

So according to all flashing methods the program is loaded and the bits are set to boot from flash. (The SAM3x8e has a ROM bootloader. This lets it flash over serial. This is flagged to run after using the erase button on the pcb. Once this is changed to boot from flash this does not run with power on any longer.)

I am at a loss. I reverified on this board that all supply pins had 3.3v. The PLL has 1.8v to all pins. The voltage levels are correct at the erase pin, the NRSTB, NRST, the SHDN is at 3.3 volt indicating the chip should be running. It seems like I have to be missing just one thing somewhere.

**END OF UPDATE.**

On this layout I am wanting to program the SAM3x8e through it's serial port. This is the lowest number port using PA8 and PA9. I think it's pin 2 and 27 on the 144 pin form factor. I have NRSTB tied to a push switch for ground RESET and PC0 with a push switch to +3.3volt. I have done something using this chip before and I don't remember having issues like this.

Problem: chip is unresponsive. Will not program through serial port and will not react at all.

Observations: all I/O pins are sitting at 3.3 volt output. This doesn't change if reset button is pressed. Otherwise pin NRSTB has 3.3 output until reset button is connected to ground. Then output is 0volts. PC0 has 0 volts until erase button is pressed then reads 3.3 volt.
Adding photos to original. Also the crystals are marked ABL-12.000MHZ-B2 and 18pf from digi-key

Oscilloscope of external crystal leads to ground. Appears there is 16 cycles per millisecond. Crystals bag is marked 12mHZ 18pf. I have 22pf capacitors to grd. Oscillator pin# 36 has a higher amplitude than that on pin#35.

I realize this is supposed to be a 12 MHz crystal. Question is would a crystal that oscillates at 16 MHz cause the processor not to respond to the serial port and then no program?

[image: oscilliscooe]

[image: crystal and chip]

[image: bottom of pcb]

[image: capacitors on crystal circuit]

[image: top side]

[image: bottom side]

Comment: definitely yes ... anything else you want to know?

Comment: I don't think your oscilloscope is up to the task of measuring the crystal. Your scope picture shows just over 1200Hz. My guess is the scope is undersampling the signal and you're seeing an alias. Where are all your bypass caps? The chip will be very unreliable without these and your pcb layout for the crystal looks suspect.

Comment: The capacitors, ferrite bead inductors and related is on the underside of the board.

Comment: Kartman, the oscilloscope made the clearest read at 1ms timeframe in either analog or digital I got 16 cycles. That would be 16khz though wouldn't it?

Comment: I count around 17 cycles over 13ms (1ms/div). My calc says 1300Hz. 
You have significant loop distance from the pins to the capacitors - you really want to use fatter tracks to minimise inductance and have the capacitors as close to the pins as possible. The crystal should be surrounded by 0V fill. Where's the ground plane?

Comment: Your problem is probably not the crystal or the finer details of the pcb layout. I'm not really familiar with the SAM 3 series - they seem to be eclipsed by the SAM 4 series and later. Do they have a built in serial bootloader? Otherwise you need to program the flash with a bootloader via jtag/swd.

Comment: Kartman, the SAM3x8e has the ability to flash over the serial after an erase reset hold. It's supposed to be part of the built in factory bootloader.

Comment: Kartman, the SAM3x8e has the ability to flash over the serial after an erase reset hold. It's supposed to be part of the built in factory bootloader using ATMEL Microchip SAM-BA. Last year I made something else that used this chip. I found the first one of two I made. The first one did do this same issue but the second one worked fine. In fact I reloaded the firmware as I made adjustments many times. The ground plane runs around the exterior of the board on the bottom copper layer.

Comment: The ground plane runs across the whole board, not around the edges. You don't have a ground plane. Yeh, I just read about SAM-BA. I'd suggest double checking everything. Ensure the 1V8 Core rail is 1V8. Check if you need to strap various pins in order for SAM-BA to operate. Use your scope to see that your serial data gets to/from the actual chip. Is the crystal actually required for SAM-BA? Read the datasheet.

Comment: The last thing I worked on used RF and couldn't have an actual ground plane. In this case I only need 6 inputs with opamps in voltage follower configuration with voltage splitter and a 3.3v supply limit, and 6 outputs through mosfets for either on/off or PWM but I also want to use the ISO11783 library I worked on for another project for configuring this module. I only need 1 working module since I was making this for use on the family farm. So I guess I will try going through it all again tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this further, I did find one pin on the SAM that had not soldered correctly. This was enough to keep the program from running even though chip flashing worked normally. Thanks to everyone who offered help in the past on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem: chip is unresponsive. Will not program through serial port and will not react at all.

When I first solder any AVR/SAM MCU on a pcb, I first use Atmel-ICE to see if the MCU works fine. Then, I burn the bootloader using Atmel-ICE. THat way, I make sure that the MCU is functional AND has a bootloader in it. (as @Kartman said to comments)

You also said:

> Kartman, the SAM3x8e has the ability to flash over the serial after an erase reset hold. It's supposed to be part of the built in factory bootloader.

Again, you need to make sure you MCU has a bootloader. (I doubt the bootloader is pre-programmed in there anyway)

Also, your board looks a bit dirty. Remove all the flux with ispropanol (or aceton but that more dangerous) in a ventilated spot. Do not breathe that thing, you will end up in the hospital wilth lungs and heart problems. Alternatively, you can use alcohol.

After that, I check the fuses using Atmel-ICE. Sometimes there is a fuse that divides clock by 8, you might have something like it and you may need to un-check it.

Alternatively to Atmel-ICE you might be able to use an Arduino and arduino IDE to burn bootloader and program the fuses (use Arduino as ISP)

After you make sure that your MCU is recognisable by an Atmel-ICE or arduino as ISP, and you have burned the bootloader, the you can try and program it using serial port.

You did not mention that your MCU is recognisable.

> I realize this is supposed to be a 12 MHz crystal. Question is would a crystal that oscillates at 16 MHz cause the processor not to respond to the serial port and then no program?

Use another Crystal, even with slower speed.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I don't have an Atmel-ICE unit. In the past I made a few boards with 2560MCU so I do have a couple of STK500 that I used for those.  The board was sprayed off with pcb cleaner alcohol based. What's left is no-clean solder flux to start with. According to Microchip the SAM-BA (to use with BOSSAC flash loader) is supposed to be preloaded on all of these from the factory.  The Arduino Due bootloader only loads the AT chip used as a USB to serial and controls the RESET and ERASE on the Due board. I'll try to check it all again today. thanks

Comment: Ok. When cleaning the pcb, you need to spray it with pcb cleaner and then rub it (with paper or cotton swabs and then with a toothbrush), and repeat that process until none is left. You also need to clean the "no-clean" solder flux if you want to have a professional result, and be sure nothing is left behind.

Comment: @Chirstianidis well I checked over both the one I assembled the other day and that other board that I had from last year that didn't work either. Voltages are good on the VDDPLL 1.8v. External serial data is getting passed through the MAX3232 interface to the pins of both SAM3x8e chips. The newest board I did not add the JTAG to but the older one has the mount holes for a JTAG header on it. I think I'm going to have to order a Atmel-ICE or compatible JTAG interface to try that and see if flashing the memeory works that way.